# WCF still maintained tomorrow

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api2

I will start a new project, and I'll need to remotely consume services. As it will be a very long run project, I am a bit skeptical about the fact that WCF will stay maintained/evolved in the future. I can also developp my new service around Web Api V2.

So my question is, WCF or Web Api (or something else), what is now commonly preferred for new projects which consume services remotely ?

Comment: Crystal ball needed, but IMO WCF will be around for many years. But I'd use MVC6 if I were starting something new today.

Comment: I agree with you, the background question is kind of "is it yet in "maintenance" mode like winforms ?"

Comment: Well since there were [new features added to WCF in .Net 4.6.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx#WCF), I'd say that it isn't in maintenance mode. (But then, there were some enhancements made to some Windows Forms controls, so even THAT is still being updated...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Matthew comments and Microsoft links, WCF is still evolving. As developpers resume containing WCF are today more numerous than WebApi, we'll go for WCF for this project (thanks again Matthew).